# animated .webp backgrounds not working on firefox but works on chromium just fine

Tags: html, css, background-image

for some reason animated webp backgrounds for css on firefox for me are not animating unless something on the screen is updating, but it works on chromium just fine, is there any way to get it to work on firefox too?

```
  body {
  margin: auto;
  display: table;
  background: url('i/blossom.webp');
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #222222;
  }
```

Comment: It seems the problem comes from `display: table;`. Do you really need this? (Note that it also affects gif files)

Comment: One really hackish solution would be to force the rerendering of the element through an `animation`, but that's really not something I can recommend, not on a table. Certainly there is a way to make your background on an other element that on the one that is displayed as a table, at least a pseudo-element.

Answer (score 1):

As Kaiido has pointed out, the problem seems to lie with the displaying of body as table.

One way round this is to remove the animated background from the body itself and put it onto a pseudo before element which is displayed as an inline-block.

Setting this as position fixed behind the main body has the same effect as setting the background-attachment to fixed on the body - ie the background remains during scrolling.

```css
body {
  margin: auto;
  display: table;
  background-color: #222222;
}

body::before {
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: inline-block;
  background: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/61/Solar_system_orrery_inner_planets.webp');
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<body></body>
```

Note: this method of fixing a background also works for Safari which at the present time has bugs in relation to background-attachment (see https://caniuse.com/?search=background-attachment ) - although testing on an iPad, IOS 15, the rendering of the webp was stepwise rather than continuous.